# if $x+\frac{1}{x}=\sqrt2$, then find the value of $x^{2022}+\frac{1}{x^{2022}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

It is question of mathematical olympiad. kindly solve it guys!
I tried a bit.I am sharing this with u...

•$x+\frac{1}{x}=\sqrt{2}$

•$x^2+1=x\sqrt{2}$

•$x^2-x\sqrt{2}+1=0$

so, $x=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{i\sqrt{2}}{2}$ or $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{i\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and
$\frac{1}{x}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{i\sqrt{2}}{2}$ or $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{i\sqrt{2}}{2}$

How can I find $x^{2022}+\frac{1}{x^{2022}}$?

Comment: What is $x$ in polar form?

Comment: In addition to what @peterwhy said, keep in mind that a polar form of complex numbers exists. This is to help us solve complex numbers raised to high powers. This is proven by DeMoivre's Theorem. Search it up for more info and help :)

Comment: I think OP made a reasonable effort to answer this, and got part of the way.  The downvotes and close votes seem harsh in this case.

Comment: Just a slightly different approach from the answers. You can also determine that x^4 = -1 and plug that in.

Answer (score 8):

The trick with this question is to try finding $x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}$, via squaring $x+\frac{1}{x}$:

$(x+\frac{1}{x})^2=x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+2$

$2=x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+2$

$0=x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}$

The fact that this equals 0 is key to solving the problem, since subtracting $\frac{1}{x^2}$ from both sides and then putting both sides to the power of 1011 solves the problem:

$x^2=-\frac{1}{x^2}$

$(x^2)^{1011}=(-\frac{1}{x^2})^{1011}$

$x^{2022}=-\frac{1}{x^{2022}}$

$x^{2022}+\frac{1}{x^{2022}}=0$

So the answer is 0 and we are done!

Comment: I was about to post the same answer, but you were faster! To OP: often, in these $x + x^{-1} = c$, find $x^{n} + x^{-n}$ problems, finding $x$ is unnecessary (that's not your main objective). Instead, use symmetry.

Answer (score 2):

Your answers for $x=(1\pm i)/\sqrt2$, $1/x=(1\mp i)/\sqrt2$ are correct, now notice that
$$
{1\over x}={\bar x},
$$
the "complex conjugate", and
$$
x^2+{\bar x}^2={1+2i-1+1-2i-1\over 2}=0
$$
and $x^4={\bar x}^4=-1$,
so
$$
\begin{align}
x^{2022}+1/x^{2022}&=x^{4\times505}x^2+{\bar x}^{4\times505}{\bar x}^2\\
&=(-1)^{505}(x^2+{\bar x}^2)\\
&=0
\end{align}
$$.

Answer (score 2):

$$x + \frac{1}{x} = \sqrt2 $$
squaring both sides,
$$x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} = 0 $$

then,
$$x^{2022} + \frac{1}{x^{2022}} = (x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2})(x^{2020} + \frac{1}{x^{2020}}) - (x^{2018}+ \frac{1}{x^{2018}}) = - (x^{2018}+ \frac{1}{x^{2018}})$$

repeat the above process,

$$x^{2022} + \frac{1}{x^{2022}} = x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

The solutions you got are  (primitive) eighth roots of unity, $\zeta_8=e^{2\pi i/8},\dfrac 1{\zeta_8}=\bar {\zeta _8}$.

Now $$\zeta _8^{2022}=(\zeta _8^8)^{252}\cdot \zeta _8^6=1\cdot \zeta _8^6=\zeta_8^6$$.  And $\dfrac 1{\zeta_8^{2022}}=\zeta_8^{-6}$.

So  $$\zeta_8^6+\zeta_8^{-6}=-i+i=0$$